# Please how to solve these errors installing spark on window. Please, anyone help find solution for these errors. I can not start the project

Tags: windows, apache-spark

To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

```html
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
21/11/02 12:09:01 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
21/11/02 12:09:02 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

21/11/02 12:09:01 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
21/11/02 12:09:02 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionenter code here

Comment: What version are you using? What command are you running? Have you tried to write Scala code on your own, and run that **outside** of the `spark-shell`?

Comment: have you created sparksession instance first before importing spark.implicits._?

Comment: I am so newbie. I use window shell command.